# Changing methods in libraries to promises

Tags: javascript, bluebird

```
converter.json2csv(MAP.fls, function (error, csv) {
    if (error) {
        return error;
    }

    file_system.writeFile(MAP.output.res, csv, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }
    });
});
```

I have this piece of code.. and I would like to know if is possible use promises with them. I don't like, and I think that doesn't make sense this two if statements, testing for errors..

If not possible.. there isn't anything that I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If library has callback interface, probably there's nothing you can do, except changing it's sources.

But you can make wrapper function which uses deferred interface, like this:

```
// let's create our wrapper module
// json2cvs.js

var Deferred = require("deferred"); // this is just for example;
var converter = require("converter");

module.exports = function(MAP) {
    var dfd = Deferred();        

    converter.json2csv(MAP.fls, function (error, csv) {
        if (error) {
            dfd.reject(error);
        }

        file_system.writeFile(MAP.output.res, csv, function (error) {
            if (error) {
               dfd.reject(error);
            }

            // some actions
            var message = "file saved";

            // success
            dfd.resolve(message);
        });
    });

    return dfd.promise;   
}
```

And then in another module you can simply require module above:

```
var json2csv = require("json2csv");

// use
json2csv(input).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

For this example I used this deferred library https://www.npmjs.com/package/deferred

But you can use any other.